# How to pass multiple parameters on an outputlink?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using the following Visualforce code to send multiple parameters (including a returl) to a controller.

```
<apex:outputLink target="_blank"  styleClass="btn addToBtn2" 
value="/apex/NewScholarRequest?SiteID={!selectedProgram}?returl=/apex/be1_Attendance{!URLENCODE('?cy='+selectedCycle+'&di='+selectedDistrict+'&si='+selectedProgram)}">
New Scholar Request
</apex:outputLink>
```

When I try to get the result in the controller constructor, I get:

```
tmp =  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('siteID');
```

I get this result:

> siteID=a0Z00000001BwnWEAS?returl=/apex/be1_Attendance?cy=a0J00000000hIKOEA2&di=a0K00000000dtALEAY&si=a0Z00000001BwnWEAS

That's the whole set of parameters, not just the first one.  Why don't they get split up?   Do I need to individually URLENCODE each parameter after the first?

Comment: I see 2 '?' try /apex/NewScholarRequest?SiteID={!selectedProgram}&returl=/apex/be1_Attendance....... Ideally I would use <apex:param> to pass parameters to the controller than this URL hack way, but thats your choice

Comment: I may well give the  <apex:param> method a try.  It certainly looks clearer than what I came up with.

Answer (score 3):

The URLENCODE call will encode the `?` and `&` delimiters whereas you really need to just encode each parameter.

One way to do that is:

```
"/apex/be1_Attendance?cy={!URLENCODE(selectedCycle)}&di={!URLENCODE(selectedDistrict)}&si={!URLENCODE(selectedProgram)}"
```

Comment: Nice catch @KeithC!